# Migrating from local files to AWS S3 in PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm migrating a PHP web application that stores pictures locally to AWS S3, and it can't go under a maintenance window.
S3 pictures will be publicly visible.

This are the steps I'm following:

1. Implement S3 api so the new pictures are stored in S3 and there's no more new files saved locally.
2. Refactor pictures listing so that it can show local and s3 pictures, the latter will be shown using public URLs.
3. Add a database flag to determine if that picture is stored locally or at S3.
4. Migrate local files to S3 using AWS CLI. There's almost a hundred thousand pictures total, I intend to do it one client a time to avoid timeout.
5. **Problem:** After migrating, I can fetch those objects at S3 but I don't have their public URL stored in my database.
6. **Solution:** Run a script through each client, fetch those database records that doesn't have public URL, fetch those URLs at S3 and than update them database records with the URLs and change it's flag to indicate that now it's stored at s3.

Is there a better/smoother way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S3 object's public URL doesn't change, so I hardcoded it.

Answer (score 1):

Is your database publicly accessible or if its a RDS instance, you could create Lambda function to insert/update record to the database once object is uploaded.

Similar to what is explained in the following [tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html)

When you upload s3 object add [user-defined metadata](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#UserMetadata) attributes to specify database primary key (could be encrypted).

Once object is uploaded to s3 lambda function will be triggered with the [payload](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-upload-deployment-pkg.html#walkthrough-s3-events-adminuser-create-test-function-upload-zip-test-manual-invoke) containing all information required to concatenate s3 object url

Comment: How would that give me public URL for the original objects?

Comment: sorry, I elaborated my answer to explain it better